# Change font size in JSPDF

Tags: font-size, jspdf

I want to change the font size in my pdf but i can´t

I tried to use doc.setFontSize(2) for example but i only can in a hardcode variable for example

```
let title = 'Hello world'
doc.setFontSize(2)    -----> thats works but if i want to change this below:


let stringRange =  padLessTen(segment.dates.start.getHours()) + ":" + padLessTen(segment.dates.start.getMinutes())
        + ' - ' + padLessTen(segment.dates.end.getHours()) + ":" + padLessTen(segment.dates.end.getMinutes())

        return  `${stringRange}`
      };
```

This is a variable that returns hours and I want to lower the font size of those hours i tried with everything doc.setFontSize(2) or styles: { fontSize(2) }  if i return `${stringRange}` + doc.setFontSize(2) it said 11:45 {object Object} and dont change the size